# The killing of civilians / the killings of civilians; the death of a million / the deaths of a million

Tags: nouns, gerunds

Consider these examples:

> ***(A)** the **killing** of civilians.
>
> **(B)** the **killings** of civilians.
>
> **(C)** the **death** of a million.
>
> **(D)** the **deaths** of a million.*

Is the **'killing'** in **(A)** a gerund? And is **'killing(s)'** in **(B)** a noun?
Is **'death'** in **(C)** an uncountable noun? Or, do **'a million (people)'** constitute a single entity so that they can be considered as singular?

I would like to know the grammatical reasoning behind these expressions.

Comment: Is there any way you can give less appalling examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's little grammatical difference between **(A)** and **(B)**, and **(C)** and **(D)**, aside from the obvious use of plurals in the latter examples. In both **(A)** and **(B)**, ***'killing(s)'*** is a gerund - a continuous form of a verb used as a noun - and in both **(C)** and **(D)** ***'death'*** is a regular, countable noun.

There is a slight difference in meaning to me in both of those examples, though:

- In **(A)**, a reference to ***'killing'*** in the singular indicates a process which happens continuously (and I'd take it to mean it has a single culprit, eg. an oppressive regime), whereas **(B)** puts more emphasis on there being distinct, numerous instances of said killings, possibly performed in different places by different people.
- Similarly in **(C)**, ***'the death'*** in singular is more likely to refer to one event - catastrophe, accident, etc. - which caused multiple people to die, while ***'the deaths'*** in **(D)** would concern multiple instances of people dying independently of each other.